# Skeleton for a CI/CD pipeline as YAML definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to to create a `yaml` definition file for a simple CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps.

My pipeline should look like this:
[image]

1. Is it possible to define the whole workflow in one definition file with different stages and jobs?
2. How can I determine which project (which GIT sub-path has triggered the build) has changed to proceed with project A/B workflow?
3. The first workflow with project A seems feasible for me. I can run the `sc` command together with `runsas` or `psexec` to start/stop the service and use a copy file task. But how can I initiate to publish the ASP.NET web application to a local directory (as I would do with VS->Publish->Local Folder)?
4. After that I guess it's the easiest way to make use of scripts to replace content, install npm packages to minify and bundle js/css files and upload these to a ftp server. Or any better/easier ideas?

If you guys can support me by creating an initial `yaml` definition just for the workflow without the details of the tasks I would really appreciate that. Maybe I get a more clear vision if you can answer my questions above.

At the moment I have a very simple initial build file:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master # for a productive deployment after manual approval
- develop # for a automatic test deployment

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'tpcemedia'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No, releases are not yet possible in yaml. You can have build stages\jobs, but it makes no sense to use them in such a simple case
2. Yaml has a [path-trigger filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#triggers), just configure a build per application. no need to complicate the build with conditions. do something like this:

build1:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include: src/proj1/*
```

build2:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include: src/proj2/*
```

3. Better to separate release and build, this way your release agent will be directly on the server and would be able to restart service locally without the need to have network access (and its more secure). It would also pull the artifacts generated by the build agent "for free".
4. Why use ftp, just use "publish artifacts" step(s), much easier.

Comment: Thank you. Some remarks to my questions/your answers. #3 Indeed, this would be simpler. But corporate policies prohibit to install any kind of agents on productive servers. I have to work with file-shares and `sc`/`net service` from jumphosts or dev machines. #4 The full version goes to IIS. A static version /Home -> index.html with some of the scripts from the project combined with some from somewhere else need to be copied via ftp to static webserver. The server is controlled by third-party and part of a huge web-farm. There is no chance to install something like a agent.

Comment: "I have to work with file-shares and sc/net service from jumphosts or dev machines". I'd like to talk to a person who thinks this is more secure, lol